# Issue with xcode 7 (GM) Swift 2 using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, swift2, xcode7

I have a problem when I want to access to the photo gallery from the user than iOS show first an alert for the permission. I have the same code in one project it show the alert in the other project iOS don't ask me for something there is only a black screen.

> The real project...
>   [image]
>
> The test project...
>   [image]

It's really weird because I use the same code...

This is my Swift code  :

```
    @IBAction func uploadImagePressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
    let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (alertController) -> Void in
        if(UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)){
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
            imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .FullScreen
            self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else{
            print("Camera not available on iDevice...")
        }
    })

    let gallery = UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (alertController) -> Void in

            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
            imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
            self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })

    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: { (alertController) -> Void in})

    alertController.addAction(cameraAction)
    alertController.addAction(gallery)
    alertController.addAction(cancel)

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Could you "Reset Contents and settings" of simulator and try these two projects again ? It should be asked in the "real project" too.

Comment: I already did that...

Comment: Could you try this code also in two project you have:
        
AVCaptureDevice.requestAccessForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) { (Bool granted) -> Void in
            if granted
            {
                
            }
        }

Comment: It doesn't work in 2 projects both?

Comment: what I have to import ?

Comment: Just add this code to your viewDidLoad() method you need to import AVFoundation to your class.

AVCaptureDevice.requestAccessForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) { (Bool granted) -> Void in if granted { } }

Comment: nope as well don't work ..(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89620/discussion-between-sabrican-ozan-and-bilalreffas).